# FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener not Calling android

Tags: java, android, firebase, onclicklistener, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am using **FirebaseInAppMessaging** and it's works. Then i register action call back using `FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener`, it's not calling.

```
public class InAppMessageClick implements FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener, FirebaseInAppMessagingImpressionListener, FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay {

String TAG = "InAppMessageClick";
@Override
public void messageClicked(InAppMessage inAppMessage, Action action) {
    // Determine which URL the user clicked
    String url = action.getActionUrl();
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "Action URL : "+url);
    // Get general information about the campaign
    CampaignMetadata metadata = inAppMessage.getCampaignMetadata();
   Log.i(TAG," Metadata : "+metadata);
}


@Override
public void impressionDetected(InAppMessage inAppMessage) {
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "impressionDetected Action URL : "+inAppMessage.getCampaignMetadata().getCampaignName());
}

@Override
public void displayMessage(InAppMessage inAppMessage, FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplayCallbacks firebaseInAppMessagingDisplayCallbacks) {
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "displayMessage Action URL : "+inAppMessage.getCampaignMetadata().getCampaignName());

}
```

}

And i register this click listener in MainActivity's onCreate

```
InAppMessageClick inAppMessageClick = new InAppMessageClick();
    FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessageDisplayComponent(inAppMessageClick);
    FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().addClickListener(inAppMessageClick);
```

i tried to register listener for two ways.

```
InAppMessageClick inAppMessageClick = new InAppMessageClick();
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().addClickListener(inAppMessageClick);`
```

Or

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().addClickListener(inAppMessageClick, new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable command) {
                LogUtils.i("MainActivity", "FIAM CLICKED EXECUTOR");
            }
       });
```

`

And using gradle

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:18.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, FirebaseInAppMessaging remove all listeners every time an activity goes to background. You can see this by putting a break point on `removeAllListeners` method of `DeveloperListenerManager` class.
Registering your listener in the `onResume` method of your main activity is a way to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to this issue opened 7 days ago?
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/681

Comment: Yes, I couldn't get any solution till now.

Comment: @AbhishekKumarSrivastav I still have the problem, even after upgrading to the latest version. Did you find any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might want to try.

1. Create a new campaign in Firebase Console (refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/compose-campaign). Don't publish it yet, because you can't test a published campaign.
2. In "Scheduling" step, select `on_foreground` as the trigger event.
3. In your app's `onResume()`, add listeners.

```
Firebase.inAppMessaging.addClickListener { inAppMessage, action ->
    // ...
}

Firebase.inAppMessaging.addImpressionListener { inAppMessage ->
    // ...
}
```

4. Run your app and put it in the background by pressing HOME button.
5. Send the test message from Firebase Console's `Test on device`, which is in "Style and content" step.
6. Bring your app to foreground and tap on your campaign's button that is not marked as "Use dismiss as the action".

At this point, both `ClickListener` and `ImpressionListener` should be called.

In-App Messaging removes all listeners except `DismissListener` when the app goes to the background, so you'd need to add listeners in `onResume()` if you want to use `on_foreground` as the trigger event.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dependencies:
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-ktx'

code on MainActivity onCreateMethod:
val firebaseIam = Firebase.inAppMessaging
firebaseIam.addClickListener { inAppMessage, action ->
            //write your functionality
            Log.d("here","successful)

        }
```

Comment: please, add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Above method will give u message click listener even in testing InApp message but make sure while creating the campaign u have uncheck the box "Use dismiss as Action"